# Override 2nd optional parameter while leaving the 1st optional parameter alone

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I'm still pretty new to C#, so I'm looking for a way to only override certain optional parameters while leaving others alone. I would have something like this:

```
Private void DoSomething(string Var1, int Var2 = 0, string Var3 = "TEST"){//Do something}
```

Then when I try to do this:

```
DoSomething("my variable",,"OK");
```

I always get an error saying parameter missing. Is there a way to override optional parameters without overriding optional parameters before them?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You use a named argument:

```
DoSomething("My variable",Var3:"OK");
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes

Longer answer: use the parameter names and, preferably, use clear names for those parameters.

Example:

```
DoSomething(Var1: "my variable", Var3:"OK");
```